# path parameter: Invalid path Scala Play Config file

Tags: scala, playframework, playframework-2.0, playframework-2.3

I am getting a parsing exception inside of my `application.conf` file.

Here is my `application.conf`

```
db.test.driver = org.postgresql.Driver 
db.test.user = "postgres"
db.test.password = "postgres"
db.test.url = "jdbc:postgresql://localhost:5432/gasguru"
```

here is the code that I am trying to use to read from my `application.conf`

```
trait DbConfigWeb extends DbConfig { qualifier: DbQualifier =>

  def url: String = current.configuration.getString(qualifier + ".url").get
  println(url)
  def username: String = current.configuration.getString(qualifier + ".user").get
  def password: String = current.configuration.getString(qualifier + ".password").get
  def driver: String = current.configuration.getString(qualifier + ".driver").get
  override def database: DatabaseDef = JdbcBackend.Database.forURL(url, username, password, null, driver)

  override implicit val session = database createSession
}

trait DbQualifier {
  val qualifier: String
}

trait DbProductionQualifier extends DbQualifier {
  override val qualifier = "db.production"
}

trait DbTestQualifier extends DbQualifier {
  override val qualifier = "db.test"
}
```

here is the test case I am trying to run:

```
class DbConfigWebUnitTest extends PlaySpec with OneAppPerSuite with BeforeAndAfterAll {


      "DbConfigWebTest" must {
        "have the same username as what is defined in application.conf" in {
          val dbManagementWeb = new DbConfigWeb with DbTestQualifier
          dbManagementWeb.username must be("postgres")
        }

        "have the same password as what is defined in application.conf" in {
          val dbManagementWeb = new DbConfigWeb with DbTestQualifier
          dbManagementWeb.username must be("postgres")
        }


        "have the qualifier db.test" in { 
          val dbManagementWeb = new  DbConfigWeb with DbTestQualifier
          dbManagementWeb.qualifier must be ("db.test")
        }
      }


    }
```

and finally the error message:

```
[info] - must have the qualifier db.test *** FAILED ***
[info]   com.typesafe.config.ConfigException$BadPath: path parameter: Invalid path 'com.suredbits.web.db.DbConfigWebUnitTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3$$anon$3@1e2cbe08.url': Token not allowed in path expression: '$' ('$' not followed by {, '$' not allowed after '$') (you can double-quote this token if you really want it here)
[info]   at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser.parsePathExpression(Parser.java:1095)
[info]   at com.typesafe.config.impl.Parser.parsePath(Parser.java:1135)
[info]   at com.typesafe.config.impl.Path.newPath(Path.java:224)
[info]   at com.typesafe.config.impl.SimpleConfig.hasPath(SimpleConfig.java:80)
[info]   at play.api.Configuration.reportError(Configuration.scala:743)
[info]   at play.api.Configuration.readValue(Configuration.scala:132)
[info]   at play.api.Configuration.getString(Configuration.scala:151)
[info]   at com.suredbits.web.db.DbConfigWeb$class.url(DbConfigWebProduction.scala:14)
[info]   at com.suredbits.web.db.DbConfigWebUnitTest$$anonfun$1$$anonfun$apply$mcV$sp$3$$anon$3.url(DbConfigWebUnitTest.scala:27)
[info]   at com.suredbits.web.db.DbConfigWeb$class.$init$(DbConfigWebProduction.scala:15)
[info]   ...
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are concatenating a object with a string, which will call the default toString method that produces `your.class.name@hash`. You need to call the method from the trait instead:

```
current.configuration.getString(qualifier.qualifier + ".url").get
```

and do the same on the other calls.

Or you can just override the `toString` method to return the qualifier value and use it the same way you are using it now

```
trait DbQualifier {
  val qualifier: String
  override def toString = qualifier
}
```